# find values in code using selenium

Tags: selenium

I need to print names of friends list of facebook account  which are in the code.I am using java, webdriver, eclipse. so how can i do it..?
My code is:

```
hc_location=friends_tab">
<div class="clearfix _42ef">
<div class="_6a rfloat _ohf">
<div class="uiProfileBlockContent">
<div class="_6a">
<div class="_6a _6b" style="height:100px"/>
<div class="_6a _6b">
<div class="fsl fwb fcb">
<a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100004354923588&extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22friends_tab%22%7D" data-gt="{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"100004354923588","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AatFZB3bSKV1-v1-TR2ok-dPAbN9rzl_3kU0pGsa25fiWaVHx5-bjHLWKDd3viMwgv1yaRLvlMdX3-X03tbhtjEZ","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"738277089"}" href="https://www.facebook.com/sivaramakrishna.churukuri?fref=pb&hc_location=friends_tab">Sivaramakrishna Churukuri</a>
</div>
<a class="uiLinkSubtle" data-gt="{"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AauP9VE6r6RJg9RklXss8Ij7rBBpi8gQXqOJbBK3dhvJV9-qk6TEr1oJklIPahLAfMkkWVB_SIlPbQ6vlwDJIe13","coeff2_action":"13","coeff2_pv_signature":"738277089"}" href="https://www.facebook.com/sivaramakrishna.churukuri/friends">103 friends</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="_698">
<div class="clearfix _5qo4">
<a class="_5q6s _8o _8t lfloat _ohe" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100003212947042&extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22friends_tab%22%7D" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="https://www.facebook.com/kamesh.peri.5?fref=pb&hc_location=friends_tab">
<div class="clearfix _42ef">
<div class="_6a rfloat _ohf">
<div class="uiProfileBlockContent">
<div class="_6a">
<div class="_6a _6b" style="height:100px"/>
<div class="_6a _6b">
<div class="fsl fwb fcb">
<a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100003212947042&extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22friends_tab%22%7D" data-gt="{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"100003212947042","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AauBaMRFF-E1ITEW9Rva9NO6xU67IbSuJZEgYIzHEB4CVZ_e6MM2fHCqF75opZvYnSlnHSOqYQ3EaZucFsMq6WMd","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"738277089"}" href="https://www.facebook.com/kamesh.peri.5?fref=pb&hc_location=friends_tab">Kamesh Peri</a>
</div>
<a class="uiLinkSubtle" data-gt="{"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"Aat-c_R0rmMkazYv1tQfMWB254d055vp_28IHeIbPNodi5AgjkwSKK0gxoikjPCHdstPnIZgBGM4DLQexsa3ctZ5","coeff2_action":"13","coeff2_pv_signature":"738277089"}" href="https://www.facebook.com/kamesh.peri.5/friends">374 friends</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="_698">
<div class="clearfix _5qo4">
<a class="_5q6s _8o _8t lfloat _ohe" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=678773097&extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22friends_tab%22%7D" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="https://www.facebook.com/rchalasani?fref=pb&hc_location=friends_tab">
<div class="clearfix _42ef">
<div class="_6a rfloat _ohf">
<div class="uiProfileBlockContent">
<div class="_6a">
<div class="_6a _6b" style="height:100px"/>
<div class="_6a _6b">
<div class="fsl fwb fcb">
<a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=678773097&extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22friends_tab%22%7D" data-gt="{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"678773097","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AasX8OsfTavfyAhEpE-iOv9PuaD2vgAhBs9ByrQ72VN1TWGanfz8Cc6UlLt7hsMf-Js","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"738277089"}" href="https://www.facebook.com/rchalasani?fref=pb&hc_location=friends_tab">Rama Chalasani</a>
</div>
<a class="uiLinkSubtle" role="button" rel="dialog" href="/browse/mutual_friends/?uid=678773097" ajaxify="/ajax/browser/dialog/mutual_friends/?uid=678773097" data-tooltip-uri="/ajax/mutual_friends/tooltip.php?friend_id=678773097" data-hover="tooltip">24 mutual friends</a>
```

I need to print Sivaramakrishna Churukuri, Kamesh Peri, Rama Chalasani which are in

```
<a></a>
```

tags

Thanks in advance.

I have tried this

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("smallfishhh4@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("password");
       // driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_n")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='loginbutton']/input")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("headerTinymanName")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-medley-id='pagelet_timeline_medley_friends']")).click();
       // List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElement(By.className("fsl fwb fcb"));


        List<WebElement> allNames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='fsl fwb fcb']/a"));
        //List<WebElement> allNames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='uiProfileBlockContent']/a"));
        int num = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul")).size();
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println(allNames.size());

        for(int j=0; j<num; j++){
        for(int i=0;i<allNames.size();i++){
            System.out.println(allNames.get(i).getText());
            names = names+allNames.get(i).getText();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get friend list using Selenium is web scraping and you should not do it, its illegal. Instead use the graph api with Java to achieve your goal. Below is one example. Another option you can use is RestFB(http://restfb.com/legacy-rest-api.html)

```
public void getIds(){
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            String query = "select uid from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())";
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("q", query);
            Request request = new Request(session, "/me/friends", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                            Log.d("Id's :", "Response = "+response);
                        }
                    });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request); 
        }
```